# Defining SQL function parameters in QGIS model for PostgreSQL Execute tool

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, postgresql, qgis-modeler

I am looking at creating a QGIS model in which the "PostgreSQL execute and load SQL" tool is used to run a SQL function I have created which looks like the following:

```
main.drawpolygon(postcode text[], in_buffer integer)
```

I can successfully call this using the tool. For example I could call:

```
select * from main.drawpolygon(array['SW1A 1AA'], 20)
```

**Question**

Is there a way in QGIS model builder that I can define the function parameters *Postcode* and *in_buffer* using model inputs so that users do not need to amend the sql query (many users are not familiar with sql or any coding language)?

Note that *Postcode* can be passed as an array. I am using QGIS 3.16.